# Cannot split a text string in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I want to store in a variable the current version of my scala compiler. To find the scala compiler version I can run the command `scalac -version` to get the following output:

```
$> scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

I know that the following command will get me *fourth* word in the space separated string:

```
> N=4; echo "Scala compiler version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL" | grep "Scala compiler" | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}'
2.11.6
```

However, if instead of using the hard coded string I use the `scalac -version` as input to `echo` command the result string is not split:

```
> N=4; echo "$(scalac -version)" | grep "Scala compiler" | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}'
Scala compiler version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

How can I get the result on the second code snippet from the third code snippet?

Thanks

Comment: Change `"${scalac -version)"` to `"${scalac -version}"`; you're using a closing parenthesis instead of a closing curly brace.

Comment: That last command line contains a syntax error. Post the real command you need help with.

Comment: Yes, it does contain a syntax error. I was using the error-free command on my computer, I only made the mistake typing the question. My apologies, the issue still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or with `cut`

```
scalac -version 2>&1|cut -d' ' -f4
```

like @David C. Rankin said, `scalac -version` output on `stderr`, so `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`

Comment: I'm adding you as the correct answer as you specify the `stderr` issue in your answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
scalac -version | grep -Po '(?<=version ).*?(?= )'
```

or awk:

```
scalac -version | awk '{print $4}'
```

Output:

```
2.11.6
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have run both commands on my bash terminal and I still get the full string back as output. Are you sure these are the right commands?

Comment: @DanielHernandez Does `scalac -version` output on `stdout` or `stderr`? Try `scalac -version 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=version ).*?(?= )'`

Comment: You are right! `scalac -version` outputs to `stderr`, I have no idea why this is the case. Thanks!